# Execution of a particular stepfunction(state machine) among multiple executions of same state machine

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli, aws-step-functions

I am trying to restart a state machine which is in pause state,In my case there are multiple executions of the same state machine in which I am restarting state machine and state machine is restarting the executions which are paused first(FIFO order).

I have execution Id of an execution, is ther any API to restart particular execution using execution Id?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are four valid states for a state machine execution:

1. Success
2. Failed
3. Canceled
4. In Progress

There is no 'paused' state. If you cancel a running execution it will appear as `aborted`. There is no API to 'restart' an execution which has already been created. You can start a new execution with same name as long as execution is in `In progress` state.